# Who uses sys.modules['__builtin__'] in any case to store data?

Tags: python

I was working on some python code (written around 2011) and realized the following line that keeps a global var as follows:

```
setattr(sys.modules['__builtin__'], 'globalVarTest', 123)
```

and then accessing it later

```
getattr(sys.modules['__builtin__'], 'globalVarTest')
```

I just was wondering, why not use a class with a class member variable to hold data that needs to exist globally.  Or is this something where I am completely ignorant and don't see the magic behind it?

Comment: This just looks like a plainly terrible idea.

Comment: This looks like a candidate for The Daily WTF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a case in the wild, here's one [from cpython itself](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9818142b1bd20243733a953fb8aa2c7be314c47c/Python/sysmodule.c#L284-L285) (setting the global variable `_` after evaluating and displaying an interactive statement).

This is called when running the interpreter interactively -- for example:

```
>>> 999 * 999
998001
>>> _
998001
>>> import builtins
>>> builtins._
998001
```

Generally speaking though, you should ***never*** do this in a library / application.  Adding magical super-globals will not only confuse linters but also future maintainers who expect a certain set of things to be present as builtins.

Comment: Thanks Anthony, that's a good answer. I had never seen it before, and that was actually in production code O_o.